# Basic WCF hosting over TCP

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to host a wcf service in a windows service over tcp. Everything goes fine until the step of installation of the service and starting it. However when I added a client application and while trying to add a service reference to it I'm getting this error.

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException:
There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:8523. 
Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times 
in your application and that there are no other applications listening 
on this endpoint. ---> 

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address 
(protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, 
      SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionAcceptor.StartAccepting()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(
      TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(
      SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(
      TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(
      TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Only one usage of each socket 
address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, 
      SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
```

Is this due to firewall or some other issue? This is a very basic service and the end point is as below: `net.tcp://localhost:8523/CalculatorService`.

Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.CalculatorService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="Service.ICalculatorService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/CalculatorService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

and the service code:

```
 public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
            }
            myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
```

I have coped the config file from the WCF service library to windows service project and they are identical.

Comment: What does your config look like?

Comment: How do you start the service? Can you provide the code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8523/CalculatorService");
    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);
    myServiceHost.Open();
}
```

and this Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: After doing that while adding the service reference, the windows fireWall message came that it's blocking WCFSVC and asked me whether I want to unblock it, and I said yes to private network and home network but took off the option of Public networks. After doing that I'm getting this error while adding reference:

Comment: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523/CalculatorService/mex'.
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.6059775'.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.